# How can I extract a version string from a line and save it to a variable, using bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am new to scripting and I have a task which consists of extracting a version from a LOC and save it to $VERSION. The line looks like this:

`#define PROJECT_VERSION      "21.02"`

I have to extract "21.02" and save it in $VERSION, using bash.
Right now, I am using the following command:

`awk '/PROJECT_VERSION/{print $NF}' common/ESUtils.cpp`

but it return more strings. Can you help me?

Comment: I have just seen that in order to print the 3rd field I have to use $3F.

Comment: `awk '/PROJECT_VERSION/{print $NF}' file` should work for you, what is `but it return more strings` you are getting in output? Please explain it more.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using

```sh
awk '$2 == "PROJECT_VERSION"{print $3; exit}' common/ESUtils.cpp
```

That will find the first record wih Field 2 equal to `PROJECT_VERSION` and output Field 3 value, and exit right after it without looking further in the input file.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/yk1Fjz):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='#define PROJECT_VERSION      "21.02"
1 PROJECT_VERSION   "22.02"'
awk '$2 == "PROJECT_VERSION"{print $3; exit}' <<< "$s"
# => "21.02"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
VERSION=$(sed -En '/PROJECT_VERSION/s/(^.*\")([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)(\".*$)/\2/p' project.cpp)
```

Enable regular expression interpretation with -E and then search for the line with "PROJECT_VERSION". With this line, split the line into 3 sections specified in parenthesis and substitute the line for the second section only, printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be:

```
VERSION=`awk '/PROJECT_VERSION/{print $3F}' project.cpp
```